# type ViewController does not conform to protocol SKPaymentTransactiionObserver

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller

I keep getting the error even after inputing the require code. What am I missing?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtYearlyIncome: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sldPercentSaved: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblPercent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblWeeklySaved: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMonthlySaved: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblYearlySaved: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSaved25: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnRemoveAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblAdsRemoved: UILabel!

    var yearlyIncomeString = ""
    var yearlyIncomeFloat : Float = 0.0
    var percent : Float = 0.0
    var weeklySaved : Float = 0.0
    var MonthlySaved : Float = 0.0
    var YearlySaved : Float = 0.0
    var Saved25 : Float = 0.0
    var decimalValue : Float = 0.0
    var product: SKProduct!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3042973809533220/1135061595"
        self.bannerView.rootViewController = self

        let request : GADRequest = GADRequest ()

        self.bannerView.loadRequest (request)
        self.bannerView.hidden = true
        self.bannerView.delegate = self
        btnRemoveAds.hidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let products = response.products
        if (products.count != 0)
        {
            product = products[0] as SKProduct
        }

        btnRemoveAds.hidden = true

        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Ads") == nil)
        {
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
            self.getProductInfo();
        }

        if let status: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Ads"){
            if status as! NSString == "purchased" {
                self.bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.btnRemoveAds.hidden = true;
                self.btnRemoveAds.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            else {
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
                self.getProductInfo()
            }
        }
    }

    func getProductInfo(){
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments(){
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object:"smmremoveads")
            let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }

        func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]){
            for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
                if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                    switch trans.transactionState {
                    case .Purchased:
                        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                        storePurchase()
                        lblAdsRemoved.text = "Ads Removed!"
                        break
                    case .Failed:
                        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                        break
                    case .Restored:
                        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                        break
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        func storePurchase () {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("purchased", forKey: "Ads")
            self.bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.btnRemoveAds.hidden = true
            self.btnRemoveAds.enabled = false
            lblAdsRemoved.text = "Ads Removed"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sldPercentSavedACTION(sender: UISlider) {
        takeINData()
        calculate()
    }

    @IBAction func btnRemoveAdsACTION(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func btnClearACTION(sender: UIButton) {
        clear()
    }

    func takeINData () {
        if txtYearlyIncome.text == ""{
            txtYearlyIncome.text = "10000"
        }

        yearlyIncomeString = txtYearlyIncome.text!
        yearlyIncomeFloat = Float(yearlyIncomeString)!
        percent = sldPercentSaved.value
    }

    func calculate () {
        YearlySaved = yearlyIncomeFloat * percent
        MonthlySaved = YearlySaved / 12
        weeklySaved = YearlySaved / 52
        Saved25 = YearlySaved * 25
        print()
    }

    func print () {
        percent = percent * 100

        let sPercent = String(format: "%0.0f", percent)
        let sWeekly = String(format: "%0.0f", weeklySaved)
        let sMonthly = String(format: "%0.0f", MonthlySaved)
        let sYearly = String(format: "%0.0f", YearlySaved)
        let sSaved25 = String(format: "%0.0f", Saved25)

        lblPercent.text! = "\(sPercent)%"
        lblWeeklySaved.text = "$\(sWeekly)"
        lblMonthlySaved.text = "$\(sMonthly)"
        lblYearlySaved.text! = "$\(sYearly)"
        lblSaved25.text = "$\(sSaved25)"
    }

    func clear () {
        txtYearlyIncome.text! = ""
        lblWeeklySaved.text = "$"
        lblMonthlySaved.text = "$"
        lblYearlySaved.text! = "$"
        lblSaved25.text = "$"

        lblPercent.text! = "0%"
    }

    func hideKeyboard () {
        txtYearlyIncome.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
      hideKeyboard()
    }

    func round () {

    }
}
```

Comment: forgot the beginningclass ViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a missing closing brace, but it's hard to tell because your code is formatted poorly (I'll fix that for you in a moment!)

The problem is here:

```
func getProductInfo() {
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object:"smmremoveads")
        let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
       }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]){
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
```

Note how `getProductInfo` opens two braces ({) and closes only one? That's the problem: you need a second } before `func paymentQueue`.

Comment: Thanks TwoStraws that worked but it also caused a slew of unresolved identifier errors starting from the if txtYearlyIncome.text == ""{  on down ???

Comment: As a guess, it's probably because there's an extra brace after `storePurchase()`. If your error is something like, "Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction` then try removing a brace just before `sldPercentSavedACTION()`.

Comment: so rule of thumb is I get these types of errors I should check for missing or remove braces. I am asking because I am trying to add an IAP on another app and I am getting the same type ViewController does not conform to protocol SKPaymentTransactiionObserver overtime I addclass ViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver,SKProductsRequestDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you get errors everywhere from a certain point onwards, you've almost certainly got a missing brace or quote symbol :)   If you have further questions, you should post them as new questions; posting code in comments is not a good idea. If my answer solves your problem, could you please mark it as correct so others can benefit too? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much TwoStraws ur Awesome!

Comment: Forgot to tell you that worked. Wow something so simple!